Why does my PC take a long time to start, then when it's at the login screen it jumps to the desktop instantly?
Why does my PC take a long time to start, then when it's at the login screen it jumps to the desktop instantly?
It used to be fast but I don't know what happened that caused this. I even reinstalled my PC and got the latest drivers, but it's still slow at boot.
And also, the person I bought this computer from said this computer boots up fast, so I don't get it.
Here are my specs:

Intel i5-4310M @ 2.70Ghz
8GB DDR3 RAM
Solid State Drive
Intel HD Graphics 4600


How big is your SSD and how much free space do you have left? Also how long is long?

128GB, 79.2GB
It's around 2-3 minutes long, updates make it take even longer

4th gen i5 with Windows 11, I think 2-3 minutes is not that weird on a cold boot.

Yeah, but considering the person I bought this from says it's fast at boot up, so I don't understand. Also it runs my programs and games surprisingly fast.

If hybrid shutdown is enabled, turning off the computer and then on should be quick. This is not the same as a reboot, as then the drivers are also loaded.

Hybrid shutdown = Fast Startup, right?

Yes, Hybrid shutdown closes all programs and then puts the computer in hibernation. Starting the computer will bypass the boot process and resume from hibernation, then start your progams agan.

Something else you can do is to delete everything inside %temp%. Sometimes, when Windows Defender fails to do a scan, it puts a ton of DLL files and a copy of DismHost.exe in the temporary folder. Deleting everything (these require admin rights to delete) can also lower the boot times.

Please [edit] all you answers into your question as well

After our comment exchange, it appears that Hybrid shutdown was disabled, and enabling fixed this.
Hybrid shutdown works as follows, when you shutdown the computer, all programs are closed, and the computer is then placed into hibernation.
Turning the computer back on will resume from hibernation, skipping the boot process where all drivers are loaded (they are still in memory from hibernation).
The login screen is presented and your programs are then started normally.
Hybrid shutdown is enabled by default, but won't change the speed of a cold boot or a reboot, as those times, the drivers get loaded too.

Does modern Windows really take 2-3 mins for a complete cold boot on a 4th gen i5? I'm honestly surprised by that.

IIRC Windows 11 only supports 9th gen and higher.

@FrankThomas officially, yes. But there are ways to get around it. With Windows 10 being EoL next year, people have been pushing to get old computers to work with Windows 11.

something to note: the default "hybrid shutdown" (fast shutdown) setting doesn't properly "reset" settings in the gpu: if one dual-boot with linux, and have a nvidia(physical)gpu, it could pose problems to setup the graphics under linux as the card is not properly reset. (I have seen this problem on an asus ROG with an nvidia physical gpu + an amd cpu/gpu)

@marcelm Doubt it, I'm running Windows 10 on a ~15-year-old i3 with an SSD, and it's never taken more than a minute to cold boot.

@HashimAziz With Hybrid shutdown / fast boot disabled?

@marcelm he mentioned cold boot, so yea. I'm still confused why my computer does that because the seller literally advertised "fast bootup" as one of its features

Sellers say what they want to in order to get you to buy. Do not believe them. Your computer has average specs for several years ago: it won't win any races. It will certainly be faster than a Windows 95 computer from 30 years ago, so by comparison it has "fast bootup". But what does "fast bootup" mean, really? Don't rely on sellers claims when assuming your computer's appropriate specifications.

I didn't know that an i5 4th gen back than was that bad, I though  the 8GB Ram and an i5 cpu was good as I wasn't good at computer specs back then, I just bought without thinking. I regret that now

My country is in a economy crisis so something like 10$ (which was around 15000-20000 back then, reasonable) but now it's like around 55000 so buying a new computer is hard.

I live in Myanmar for anyone wondering.
